# AppCompat v7 r21 changing Alpha of the ActionBar's title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

With the previous versions of AppCompat it was easy to get the `ActionBar`'s title TextView and modify it.

There is the method I was using:

```
 private TextView getActionBarTitleView() {
     int id = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
     return (TextView) findViewById(id);
}
```

And then to change the alpha's value of the title:

```
getActionBarTitleView().setAlpha(ratio*255);
```

Now for some reasons, "action_bar_title" with the lastest AppCompat version isn't working anymore. When I tried to use my method, it returned me "null". Tried to use other id's of the `ActionBar` but I didn't find the good one.

I saw 1 post on StackOverflow from Ahmed Nawara and the only way he found for the moment was to do an Iteration over the `Toolbar`'s children views and whenever a `TexView` is found, compare it's text value with the toolbar.getTitle() to make sure that's the `TexView` we're looking at.

If someone could help me to integrate this solution in my case because I don't know how to do it actually.

Comment: Are you using the AppCompat toolbar?

Comment: No, I'm using the SupportActionBar

Comment: Why don't you use the Toolbar? As you're using the AppCompat 21 support lib, I think you should :) (http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: I didn't try the ToolBar so far but it seems like it could be a solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you got your method from [Flavien Laurent's post](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/) on making the ActionBar not boring. If you take a closer look, he detailled another technique to set the ActionBar title's alpha inspired by Cyril Mottier.

It uses a custom `AlphaForegroundColorSpan` class that extends `ForegroundColorSpan` :

```
public class AlphaForegroundColorSpan extends ForegroundColorSpan
{
    private float mAlpha;

    public AlphaForegroundColorSpan(int color)
    {
        super(color);
    }

    public AlphaForegroundColorSpan(Parcel src)
    {
        super(src);
        mAlpha = src.readFloat();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeFloat(mAlpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        ds.setColor(getAlphaColor());
    }

    public void setAlpha(float alpha)
    {
        mAlpha = alpha;
    }

    public float getAlpha()
    {
        return mAlpha;
    }

    private int getAlphaColor()
    {
        int foregroundColor = getForegroundColor();
        return Color.argb((int) (mAlpha * 255), Color.red(foregroundColor), Color.green(foregroundColor), Color.blue(foregroundColor));
    }
}
```

Then, using a `SpannableString`, you just set the alpha to the `AlphaForegroundColorSpan`, and then set this `AlphaForegroundColorSpan` to the `SpannableString` :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    spannableString = new SpannableString("ActionBar title");
    alphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(0xffffffff);
    ...
}

private void setActionBarTitle(int newAlpha)
{
    alphaForegroundColorSpan.setAlpha(newAlpha);
    spannableString.setSpan(alphaForegroundColorSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(spannableString);
}
```

Hope it helps. If it's not clear enough, give another look to Flavient Laurent's post!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working like a charm! I would like to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation for this.

Answer (score 2):

With AppCompat you should use the new toolbar including the toolbar.xml in the activity layout and importing android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

In your activity, OnCreate you will have:

```
mtoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
getActionBarTitleView().setAlpha(ratio*255);
```

at this point you are almost done and you can use reflection to access to the view (remember to import java.lang.reflect.field;) and your function will be:

```
 private TextView getActionBarTitleView() {
     TextView yourTextView = null;
        try {
          Field f = mToolBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
          f.setAccessible(true);
          yourTextView = (TextView) f.get(mToolBar);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
    return yourTextView;
}
```